# Is this "predictor" equivalent to the typical Kalman filter?

Tags: control-theory, estimation, kalman-filter

In "Introduction to Stochastic Control" by K. Astrom, page 228 Theorem 4.1, he introduces a state estimator for the discrete-time system:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x(t+1)&=\Phi x(t)+v(t)\\
y(t)&=\theta x(t)+e(t)\\
E[v(t)v(t)^T]&=R_1\\
E[v(t)e(t)^T]&=0 \\
E[e(t)e(t)^T]&=R_2
\end{aligned}
$$
where $e,v$ are normally distributed with zero mean and the initial state $x(t_0)$ normally distributed with mean $m$ and covariance $P_0$.
The theorem, attributed to Kalman, states (slightly adapted to be self-contained):

> Theorem 4.1 (Kalman)
> The estimate $\hat{x}$ at time $t+1$ of $x$ based on $y(t_0),y(t_0+1),\dots,y(t)$ which minimizes $E[a^T(x(t+1)-\hat{x})]$ for arbitrary $a$, is the conditional mean $\hat{x}(t+1|t)$ which satisfies the recursive relation:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \hat{x}(t+1|t) &= \Phi\hat{x}(t|t-1)+K(t)(y(t)-\theta\hat{x}(t|t-1))\\
> \hat{x}(t_0|t_0-1) &= m \\
> K(t) &= \Phi P(t)\theta^T(\theta P(t)\theta+R_2)^{-1} \\
> P(t) &=(\Phi-K(t)\theta)P(t)\Phi^T+R_1
> \end{aligned}
> $$

**My question:**

What is the relation between this filter and **THE** [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Details)?

The main difference I see, is that in the typical Kalman filtering setting, you want to estimate $x(t)$ given  $y(t_0),\dots,y(t)$. However, in this case, we estimate $x(t+1)$ given $y(t_0),\dots,y(t)$, this is, we lack of the measurement at $t+1$. Thus, this estimator in Astrom's book is more a predictor. In addition, the evolution equations for $\hat{x},P$ seem to be different from those of the typical Kalman filter. If I understand this filter as different from the typical Kalman one, this makes sense.

However, Astrom presents this filter as if it was **THE** Kalman filter, which confuses me. This makes me think that there might be some relation between the predictor in the Kalman filter and the one Astrom presents.

Comment: Ok, after some algebra I realized that $P(t)$ from Astrom is indeed the predictor covariance $\mathbf{P}_{k|k-1}$ from the standard Kalman filter. I thought of deleting the question, but I will leave it in case someone else falls into the same confusion in the future. Another interesting fact: Theorem 3 in the 1960 original Kalman paper is in the form Astrom gives, estimating at $t+1$ given measurements at $t_0,\dots,t$.